# How to solve error while consuming WWEx webservice?

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

i am trying to consume webservice to get freight rate from webserivce **"http://www.wwexship.com/webServices/services/FreightShipmentQuote?wsdl"** and it is giving an error that "Web service operation getShipmentSimpleQuote with parameters {....} can not be found". whereas i am providing valid loginid,password, licensekey,accountnumber and other required details.
please suggest me how to consume this webservice?
**wsdl file-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.wwexship.com" xmlns:impl="http://www.wwexship.com" xmlns:intf="http://www.wwexship.com" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.wwexship.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <complexType name="AuthenticationToken">
    <sequence>
     <element name="loginId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="licenseKey" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="accountNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <element name="AuthenticationToken" type="impl:AuthenticationToken" maxOccurs="1"/>   
   <complexType name="QuoteLineItem">
    <sequence>
     <element name="nmfcClass" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="weight" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="ArrayOfQuoteLineItem">
    <sequence>
     <element name="lineItem" nillable="true" type="impl:QuoteLineItem" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="FreightShipmentQuoteRequest">
    <sequence>
     <element name="senderCity" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="senderState" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="senderZip" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="receiverCity" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="receiverState" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="receiverZip" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="lineItems" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOfQuoteLineItem"/>
     <element name="hazmatShipment" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="insidePickup" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="liftgatePickup" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="residentialPickup" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="tradeshowPickup" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="constructionSitePickup" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="insideDelivery" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="liftgateDelivery" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="residentialDelivery" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="tradeshowDelivery" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="constructionSiteDelivery" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="notifyBeforeDelivery" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <element name="freightShipmentQuoteRequest" type="impl:FreightShipmentQuoteRequest"/>
   <complexType name="ErrorDescription">
    <sequence>
     <element name="errorDescription" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="CarrierQuoteResult">
    <sequence>
     <element name="carrierName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="carrierSCAC" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="totalPrice" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="transitDays" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="interline" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="guaranteedService" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="highCostDeliveryShipment" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="nmfcRequired" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="ArrayOfCarrierQuoteResult">
    <sequence>
     <element name="carrierQuoteResult" nillable="true" type="impl:CarrierQuoteResult" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="FreightShipmentQuoteResponse">
    <sequence>
     <element name="responseStatusCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="responseStatusDescription" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="errorDescriptions" nillable="true" type="impl:ErrorDescription"/>
     <element name="quoteResults" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOfCarrierQuoteResult"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <element name="freightShipmentQuoteResponse" type="impl:FreightShipmentQuoteResponse"/>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>
 <wsdl:message name="getShipmentSimpleQuoteResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="freightShipmentQuoteResponse" element="impl:freightShipmentQuoteResponse"/>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="FreightShipmentQuoteRequestHeaders">
  <wsdl:part name="authenticationToken" element="impl:AuthenticationToken"/>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="getShipmentSimpleQuoteRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="freightShipmentQuoteRequest" element="impl:freightShipmentQuoteRequest"/>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:portType name="FreightShipmentQuote">
  <wsdl:operation name="getShipmentSimpleQuote" parameterOrder="freightShipmentQuoteRequest">
   <wsdl:input name="getShipmentSimpleQuoteRequest" message="impl:getShipmentSimpleQuoteRequest"/>
   <wsdl:output name="getShipmentSimpleQuoteResponse" message="impl:getShipmentSimpleQuoteResponse"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:portType>
 <wsdl:binding name="FreightShipmentQuoteSoapBinding" type="impl:FreightShipmentQuote">
  <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <wsdl:operation name="getShipmentSimpleQuote">
   <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
   <wsdl:input name="getShipmentSimpleQuoteRequest">
    <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
    <wsdlsoap:header message="impl:FreightShipmentQuoteRequestHeaders" part="authenticationToken" use="literal">
    </wsdlsoap:header>
   </wsdl:input>
   <wsdl:output name="getShipmentSimpleQuoteResponse">
    <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
   </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:binding>
 <wsdl:service name="FreightShipmentQuoteService">
  <wsdl:port name="FreightShipmentQuote" binding="impl:FreightShipmentQuoteSoapBinding">
   <wsdlsoap:address location="http://www.wwexship.com/webServices/services/FreightShipmentQuote"/>
  </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**code that calls webservice is-**

```
<!--- items data --->
<cfset items = arrayNew(1) /> 
<cfset str = structNew() /> 
<cfset str.nmfcClass = "apple" />
<cfset str.weight = "15" />
<cfset arrayAppend(items, str) />

<!--- freightShipmentQuoteRequest data--->
<cfset st = structNew() /> 
<cfset st.senderCity = "Freeport" />
<cfset st.senderState = "NY" />
<cfset st.senderZip = "11520" />
<cfset st.receiverCity = "Staten Island" />
<cfset st.receiverState = "NY" />
<cfset st.receiverZip = "10314" />
<cfset st.lineItems = "#items#" />
<cfset st.hazmatShipment = "N" />
<cfset st.insidePickup = "N" />
<cfset st.liftgatePickup = "N" />
<cfset st.residentialPickup = "N" />
<cfset st.tradeshowPickup = "N" />
<cfset st.constructionSitePickup = "N" />
<cfset st.insideDelivery = "N" />
<cfset st.liftgateDelivery = "N" />
<cfset st.residentialDelivery = "N" />
<cfset st.tradeshowDelivery = "N" />
<cfset st.constructionSiteDelivery = "N" />
<cfset st.notifyBeforeDelivery = "N" />

<cfinvoke 
  webservice="http://www.wwexship.com/webServices/services/FreightShipmentQuote?wsdl"
  method="getShipmentSimpleQuote"
  username="copssship"
  password="password"
  returnvariable="retTemp">
    <cfheader name="loginId" value="copssship">
    <cfheader name="password" value="password">
    <cfheader name="licenseKey" value="hhrWQ7RMJEDKJMh4">
    <cfheader name="accountNumber" value="W922601302">
    <!---<cfheader name="AuthenticationToken" value="#stAuth#" />--->
    <cfinvokeargument name="freightShipmentQuoteRequest" value="#st#" />
  </cfinvoke>

  <cfdump var="#retTemp#"><br/>
  <cfoutput>
  <b>retTemp:</b>#retTemp#<br/><br/>
  <b>retTemp.ResponseStatusCode:</b>#retTemp.ResponseStatusCode#<br/>
  <b>retTemp.responseStatusDescription:</b>#retTemp.responseStatusDescription#<br/>
  <b>retTemp.errorDescriptions:</b>#retTemp.errorDescriptions[1]#<br/>
  </cfoutput>
```

Comment: please show the code you have tried along with a more complete error message.

Comment: Unless I missed it, I cannot see the parameters loginId/password/licenseKey in the webservice definition. Maybe your problem is the authentication?

Comment: Could you link to any documentation you're following. As Cyril pointed out, the login/license info isn't present in the WSDL, so they may using http/basic authentication or something else to Authenticate you

Comment: @barnyr: i have updated my question with wsdl details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to test this solution as i'm not able to login to the service, however it looks like getShipmentSimpleQuote takes a single struct argument called "freightShipmentQuoteRequest", with the keys you are trying to pass as arguments within it.

```
<cfinvoke 
  webservice="http:.....FreightShipmentQuote?wsdl"
  method="getShipmentSimpleQuote"
  returnvariable="aTemp">
    <cfinvokeargument name="freightShipmentQuoteRequest" value="#{
      "senderCity" = "Freeport",
      "senderState" = "NY",
      ....
    }#" />
</cfinvoke>
```

If that doesn't work you could try prefexing all your fields "freightShipmentQuoteRequest." ie.

```
 <cfinvokeargument name="freightShipmentQuoteRequest.senderCity" value="Freeport"/>
```

What i can not see in the wsdl is any reference to the login parameters.

Comment: please find wsdl details in above question detail.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very much to me like there's a mismatch between the arcuments you're passing and those expected. Here's 2 things I'd try:

1: Use foo=CreateObject("webservice","http://server/wsdl"); then dump the object. You should see methods and arguments on it, which may differ from your arguments above.

2: Download and install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com). Then start it and add proxyServer="localhost" proxyPort="8888" to your  call. ColdFusion will now route all web service requests through Fiddler and you can examine what's being passed to and from the remote server. It's quite a powerful technique for this kind of thing.

I think Chris is right, you need to be passing a struct as an argument. I can invoke the service with the code below:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset shipService = CreateObject("webservice","http://www.wwexship.com/webServices/services/FreightShipmentQuote?wsdl")>
<cfdump var="#shipService#">
<cfset response=shipService.getShipmentSimpleQuote({})>
<cfdump var="#response#">
<cfdump var="#response.getResponseStatusCode()#">
<cfdump var="#response.getResponseStatusDescription()#">
```

The service is returning a fail code, but it does execute. The WSDL defines all members of FreightShipmentQuoteRequest as nillabla, which is why my code works, but when you come to implement is properly, you may need to use an array of structs for the lineItems element.